# Duda con método en Python

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Encontré este código que permite cambiar de frame en tkinter (https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-switch-frames-in-tkinter/). Decidí simplificarlo un poco, y quedó así:

```
import tkinter as tk
    
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._frame = False
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class()
        if self._frame:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        tk.Label(self, text="Start page", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)
 
        tk.Button(self, text="Go to page one", command=lambda: app.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        tk.Label(self, text="Page one", font=('Helvetica', 18, "bold")).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=5)

        tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page", command=lambda: app.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Descubrí por casualidad que el script funciona igual de bien haciendo los siguientes cambios:

1. En el método `switch_frame`, en la variable `new_frame`, dejar a `frame_class` sólo con paréntesis

```
def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class()
        if self._frame:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
```

2. En los botones de las clases `PageOne` y `PageTwo`, poner `app` junto al `.switch_frame` y la clase a la que se cambiará de frame.

```
tk.Button(self, text="Go to page one", command=lambda: app.switch_frame(PageOne)).pack()
```

```
tk.Button(self, text="Go back to start page", command=lambda: app.switch_frame(StartPage)).pack()
```

Precisamente son esos puntos los que no entiendo. Será que los paréntesis vacíos de `frame_class()` se refieren a la clase SampleApp, y que `app` se pone junto a `.switch_frame` por ese mismo motivo?

Comment: Bueno, eso tiene que ver con los métodos de instancia y métodos de clase, además creo que no es necesario poner los paréntesis si no recibe ningún argumento, tal vez elabore una respuesta :)

Answer (score 3):

Cabe aclarar que no se mucho de Tkinter por lo que me puedo equivocar en algunas cosas, pero si sé de *POO*. Así que procedo a la explicación:

### Clases

Las clases proveen una forma de empaquetar datos y funcionalidad juntos.Cuando creas una *clase* se crea un  nuevo tipo de *objeto*, lo cual permite crear varias *instancias* del mismo. Ejemplo:

```py
#se crea una clase llamada "Miclase"
class Miclase:
    atributo = "soy un atributo"
```

Esto lo que hace es definir una clase para posteriormente ser utilizada. A continuación la usamos

```
obj = Miclase() #crea un objeto de tipo "Miclase"
obj.atributo
#salida -> 'soy un atributo'
```

**Uso de paréntesis**
El uso de paréntesis al definir una clase no es necesario si esta no hereda otra clase, pues en los paréntesis se le pasa una *clase padre* para que herede de esta sus métodos y atributos. Pero al crear nosotros una clase *normal* o no aplicar *Herencia* no necesitamos pasarle una *clase padre* por lo que bien pueden omitirse los parentesis

> Nota:
> Todas las clases por defecto heredan de la clase `Object()`

#### Atributos de clase y Atributos de instancia

Voy a hablar de los Atributos solo para hacer mas breve y sencilla la explicación, con los métodos pasa casi lo mismo, no hay mucha diferencia.

Primero hay que saber que es una instancia. Una instancia es cuando se *crea* el objeto por primera vez y luego se procede a usarlo. Ejemplo:

```py
obj = Miclase() #se crea un objeto de tipo "Miclase"
obj.atributo #aqui accedemos a su atributo

#creamos otro objeto
obj2 = Miclase() #se crea otro objeto de tipo "Miclase"
obj2.atributo #aqui accedemos a su atributo
```

Bueno ahora que pasa si queremos cambiar el valor del atributo de la primera instancia?

```
obj.atributo = "cambio"
```

Ok ahora hemos modificado el atributo de la instancia de la clase `Miclase()`

```py
#imprimimos el valor del atributo de la otra instancia
print(obj2.atributo )
#salida -> 'cambio'
```

¿Por que pasa esto?. Pues esto pasa por que la variable declarada en la clase `Miclase()` es un atributo de clase, esto quiere decir que compartirá su valor para todas las instancias de esa clase (no es único por cada instancia), como no es un atributo de instancia podemos acceder a el sin necesidad de instanciarlo

```
atributo = Miclase.atributo
print(atributo)
#salida -> 'soy un atributo'
```

Como vez esto puede hacerse sin la necesidad de usar paréntesis (aunque también se puede)

Bueno y como creamos un atributo de instancia?, acaso basta con hacer `obj = Miclase()` y `obj2 = Miclase()`?, la respuesta es no, primero tenemos que definir un *constructor* para la clase.

> Las clases son consientes que existen

```py
class Miclase:
    atributo = "soy un atributo"
    def __init__(self): #hace referencia a la clase
        self.atributo2 = "soy otro atributo" #decimos que pertenezca a la instancia
```

Como puedes ver, se utiliza la palabra `self` este es un parametro, pues hace referencia a la misma clase, `self` no es una palabra reservada, solo es un estandar, puedes poner cualquier variable en su lugar.

Ahora si, instanciamos nuestras clases

```py
obj = Miclase() #creamos un objeto
obj2 = Miclase() #creamos otro objeto

obj.atributo2 = "cambio" #cambias el atributo de instancia de obj
print(obj.atributo2)#imprimimos
#salida -> 'cambio'

#imprimimos el atributo de instancia de obj2
print(obj2.atributo2)#imprimimos
#salida -> 'soy otro atributo'
```

### Herencia

La herencia es una parte fundamental de la *POO* y es muy útil para no volver a escribir código que ya existe, la herencia en resumen se puede interpretar como: una *clase padre* la cual le *da* sus cosas (atributos y métodos) a sus *hijos*, si un padre tiene un reloj, este padre le puede dar el reloj a su hijo, esto es la herencia.

Una clase hija puede heredar de múltiples *clases padres* (piensa como una familia de 3 padre, madre e hijo), pues los padres le heredaran sus cosas a la clase hija. Vamos con un ejemplo

```py
class Padre:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = "Jose"
        self.apellido = "aguilar"

    def mostrar_nombre(self):
        print(f"soy {self.nombre}{self.apellido}")

class Madre:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = "Maia"
        self.apellido = "Rosales"
    
    def saludar(self):
        print(f"Hola! soy {self.nombre}")

#creamos una clase hija
class Hijo(Padre,Madre):
    def __init__(self):
        #super().__init__()
        self.nombre = "jorge"
```

Si creamos una instancia de la clase `Hijo()` y accedemos a su atributo nombre no pasara nada, pero que pasa si queremos ejecutar algún método de sus clases padres?

```py
hijo = Hijo()
hijo.mostrar_nombre()
```

Esto nos dará un error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d56678b88e8c> in <module>()
----> 1 hijo.mostrar_nombre()

<ipython-input-1-92a7f55bdbf0> in mostrar_nombre(self)
      5 
      6     def mostrar_nombre(self):
----> 7         print(f"soy {self.nombre} {self.apellido}")

AttributeError: 'Hijo' object has no attribute 'apellido'
```

Nos dice que no tiene un atributo `Apellido`, pero se supone que el hijo debería heredar su apellido, no?, pues no exactamente, pero si queremos poder usar los atributos y métodos de otras clases padres se utiliza la función `super().__init__()` que sirve para inicializar las clases padres, esto es muy útil cuando se tiene demasiados métodos, además se puede cambiar sus atributos

```py
class Hijo(Padre,Madre):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()#inicializamos las clases padres
        self.nombre = "jorge" #renombramos al hijo

hijo = Hijo()
hijo.mostrar_nombre()
#salida -> soy jorge aguilar
```

Como vemos nos muestra lo que debería, pero con diferente nombre ya que renombramos el atributo `nombre`.

---

Tanto los atributos como los métodos de instancia solo afectan a su misma instancia y no a todo el objeto, es decir cada uno cambia y maneja sus propias variables, si un objeto requiere que una de sus instancia modifique un valor y que el cambio sea global, esto será hecho mediante un atributo o método de clase, mientras si solo se quiere modificar a si mismo, sin afectar al resto, será con un método o atributo de instancia.

Esta es la base de las clases y *POO* luego existen otras cosas, todo esto es importante si quieres saber como Tkinter funciona y maneja todo. Si tienes alguna duda me avisas y te ayudare. :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Es muy útil. Tengo una duda, pero con la función super(). Al menos en lo que sé, super() permite invocar métodos o atributos de la clase padre desde clases hijas. En el código que puse, SampleApp hereda tk.Tk, y PageOne hereda tk.Frame, y tiene la función super(). O sea que hereda tk.Frame, pero a la vez hereda cosas de la clase padre StartPage?

Comment: lo siento me falto agregar lo de la función `super()`, en un momento edito la respuesta hablando de eso

Comment: @Gagxz la respuesta fue editada añadiendo la explicación correspondiente